# wso2is - is it possible to disable the basic authenticator?

Tags: authentication, wso2-identity-server

Using WSO2 IS (5.0.0.SP1 or 5.1.0) - is it possible to disable the default basic authenticator?

The reason is - at the client a custom authenticator is used to provide additional security measures (one time password, client certificate, ..).

Once the user forces use of the basic authenticator authentication (e.g. using /samlsso?spEntityID=any_invalid_data_here), the user is authenticated only with its username and password skipping any additional authentication. Once authenticated, the IS won't validate other security measures (assuming the username and password is not always enough and additional authentication is required by the client or even sec standards).

Seeing the application-authentication.xml config file, I've tried to disable the basic authenticator there or replace it in the default Sequence config with no success.

Comment: can you attach an image of the local and outbound authentication configuration of your SP?

Comment: Chamila - I could, but until the SP config is used with normal login flow, it is all ok (the custom authenticator is used and it works) :) The goal here is to prevent use of the basic authenticator when invalid parameters are provided, so the user should have NO option to login using only the basic credentials. Good example is misuse of the IdP initiated SSO, providing invalid EntityID

Comment: I was asking for an image of your configuration to check if there is any issue  on it?

Comment: Apparently the IdP-initiated SSO with invalid issuer seems fixed in 5.1.0, so I will advice the client to migrate :) At least it won't be so easy to authenticate outside the defined authenticators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the question: IdP-initiated SSO with invalid issuer seems fixed in 5.1.0, where the authenticator chain is better enforced